# How To Use Highmaps Data In JSON Not Labeled 'value'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a data set that contains many fields. I have no control over the creation of this JSON. Sample:

```
data = [
    {
    'maparea':'3704000063',
    'relatedsource':null,
    'empcount':'198390',
    'response':'78',
    'mean':'61663.00',
    },
...
]
```

The chart code is:

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: geojson
    },

    title: {
        text: 'GeoJSON in Highmaps'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        tickPixelInterval: 100
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        keys: ['maparea', 'relatedsource', 'empcount', 'response', 'mean'],
        joinBy: ['fips', 'maparea'],
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#a4edba'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.properties.postal}'
        }
    }]
});
```

The geoJSON uses `fips` to label the areas (in this case counties in NC). The map shows the state and county elements. However, no data is used to plot. This is because the HighMaps code is expecting a `value` element to be present in the data I think.

Is there a way to tell HighMaps what element in the data set to use to shade the choropleth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any option to map your unique data shape to the [expected keys in the data according to the docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data). Per your comment this is possible with an array, but it doesn't seem to be possible with an object.

However, it's pretty simple to just remap your object to the required shape. The code below gives a partial example.

```
let dataMapped = data.map(obj => { 
   var median = Number(obj.median);       
   return Object.assign(obj, { name: obj.maparea, value: median });
});
```

And then use `dataMapped` as the value for your data.

There might be a more elegant way to do this in ES6 with object spread and avoid the `Object.assign` I am using to merge the old object with new attributes, but I don't have time to research that at the moment.

Comment: That produces no change in map rendering. That is also not how `keys` works. It is a mapping of the array locations in a data point to the options (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.keys).It is not a mapping from 'x' to 'y' for `['x', 'y']` but rather a listing of the ordinal position of un-named array values to some sort of chart option. What I am looking for is something similar to the `joinBy` setting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your interpretation of `keys` is wrong. Their working example clearly shows it being used to map to the `value` property of the expected data shape. But if you can create a working example on JS Fiddle, like they have, I'll be happy to try to get it working for you.

Comment: Here is example jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/pmntuc1w/. I would like to show `median` value for example.

Comment: I am getting a 'connection timed out' for your json endpoint.

Comment: You were right about `keys`. It's only for arrays. But I was able to get it working. Please see my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, that is excellent. I need to make sure IE plays nice with this as that is one of our target browsers.